# Apache doesn't process Korean Characters in Pretty Permalink

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, apache2, webserver

I'm using WP with wpml with korean as default language, during language switching it apparently uses korean characters in the permalink like this.

`https://www.example.kr/?lang=en - 영어`

I'm using Nginx reverse proxy to Apache, and apparently Apache2 doesn't read that korean characters, any directions what am i suppose to do? Searching Apache Korean doesn't return anything in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

From this article [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/320994) try these steps:

1. Backup your `/etc/apache2/conf.available/charset.conf`

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/apache2/conf.available/charset.conf /etc/apache2/conf.available/charset.conf.bak
   ```
2. Open `charset.conf` in your favourite editor:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/apache2/conf.available/charset.conf
   ```
3. Add the following lines in there:

   ```
   AddDefaultCharset off
   AddCharset ISO-2022-KR .iso2022-kr .kis
   AddCharset ISO-2022-CN .iso2022-cn .cis
   AddCharset Big5 .Big5 .big5
   ```
4. Reload your apache server:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 reload
   ```

Now test it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i tried your solution and it's still processing it as garbage.